# ASP.NET Windows Authentication Login screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an iPad app and I am looking to add authentication to it. I have a login page with the username and password field in the app.

Now I am able to send the username and password to an ASP.NET API. Now what I am looking to do is take the username and password and authenticate that user with Windows Authentication to login. After they login, Am I able to authenticate them before they do anything (i.e. run a query)

I found this article:

http://geekswithblogs.net/manjunath.k/archive/2014/09/23/windows-authentication-in-asp.net-web-application.aspx

it appears I wanna do something like this:

```
var user = username; (username comes from the app)
if(user.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)){
    //user exists
}
```

but how would I authenticate the password ? I am very confused.

Comment: This code is unrelated to authentication, it just checks the role of the authenticated user. With Windows authentication the *browser* will ask for the username/password right away. An alternative is to create a form to which you will redirect the user so he can enter the credentials. This is covered in all ASP.NET tutorials, eg in `www.asp.net`

Comment: So I guess my question is, this there away to create a custom authentication page ?

Comment: Check the tutorials. Asking for tutorials is explicitly out of scope in SO